# Flex/AS3 - calling a function dynamically using a String?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Is it possible to call a function in AS3 using a string value as the function name e.g.

```
var functionName:String = "getDetails";

var instance1:MyObject = new MyObject();

instance1.functionName(); // I know this is so wrong, but it gets the point accross:)
```

**UPDATE**

The answer from @Taskinoor on accessing a function is correct:

```
instance1[functionName]();
```

And to access a property we would use:

```
instance1[propertyName]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
instance1[functionName]();
```

Check [this](http://asgamer.com/2009/using-string-variables-to-call-functions-in-as3) for some details.

Comment: Nice one, was difficult to google for an answer, this is what I was after.

Comment: Just to piggyback on this, you can ask the instance if it has a function or var using the `in` keyword:  `if(functionName in instance1)`

Answer (score 2):

You may use function.apply() or function.call() methods instead in the case when you dont know whether object has such method for instance.

```
var functionName:String = "getDetails";
var instance1:MyObject = new MyObject();
var function:Function = instance1[functionName]
if (function)
    function.call(instance1, yourArguments)
```

Comment: As a side note, the advantage here is that apply() allows you to pass the parameters in an array instead of specifying them inline.

Comment: @Luis: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27822620/1762224) below. You can still specify them inline by passing the `...args`. You just have to make sure that the switch can handle the length of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I have created the following wrappers for calling a function. You can call it by its name or by the actual function. I tried to make these as error-prone as possible.

The following function converts a function name to the corresponding function given the scope.

```
public static function parseFunc(func:*, scope:Object):Function {
    if (func is String && scope && scope.hasOwnProperty(funcName)) {
        func = scope[func] as Function;
    }
    return func is Function ? func : null;
}
```

### Call

***Signature*: `call(func:*,scope:Object,...args):*`**

```
public static function call(func:*, scope:Object, ...args):* {
    func = parseFunc(func, scope);
    if (func) {
        switch (args.length) {
            case 0:
                return func.call(scope);
            case 1:
                return func.call(scope, args[0]);
            case 2:
                return func.call(scope, args[0], args[1]);
            case 3:
                return func.call(scope, args[0], args[1], args[2]);
            // Continue...
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

### Apply

***Signature*: `apply(func:*,scope:Object,argArray:*=null):*`**

```
public static function apply(func:*, scope:Object, argArray:*=null):* {
    func = parseFunc(func, scope);
    return func != null ? func.apply(scope, argArray) : null;
}
```

---

### Notes

#### Call

The switch is needed, because both `...args` and `arguments.slice(2)` are Arrays. You need to call `Function.call()` with variable arguments.

#### Apply

The built-in function ([`apply(thisArg:*, argArray:*):*`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#apply%28%29)) uses a non-typed argument for the `argArray`. I am just piggy-backing off of this.

Comment: Also, should the apply() argsArray parameter not be typed to Array?

Comment: I added a notes section to answer some of your questions.