# dynamically call a function

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

How can we dynamically call a function. I have tried below code:

```
public function checkFunc() : void
{
  Alert.show("inside function");
}
public var myfunc:String = "checkFunc";
public var newFunc:Function=Function(myfunc);
newFunc();
```

But it gives error:

> Call to a possibly undefined method
>   newFunc.

In place of `newFunc()`, I tried calling it as `this[newFunc]()`, but that throws error:

> The this keyword can not be used in
>   static methods. It can only be used in
>   instance methods, function closures,
>   and global code

Any help in calling the function dynamically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flex/AS3 - calling a function dynamically using a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489291)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex/AS3 - calling a function dynamically using a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489291/flex-as3-calling-a-function-dynamically-using-a-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions work the same way properties to, you can assign them the same way you assign variables, meaning that all the funky square bracket tricks work for them too.

```
public function checkFunc() : void
{
  Alert.show("inside function");
}
public var myfunc:String = "checkFunc";
public var newFunc:Function = this[myfunc];
newFunc();
```

Answer (score 3):

From [taskinoor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489291/flex-as3-calling-a-function-dynamically-using-a-string/4489353#4489353) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489291/flex-as3-calling-a-function-dynamically-using-a-string):

> ```
> instance1[functionName]();
> ```
>
> Check [this](http://asgamer.com/2009/using-string-variables-to-call-functions-in-as3) for some details.

Comment: whatever is given in this link is what i have done in above code...but it is giving errors..:(

Comment: @sandy Is the method contained in a static class?

Answer (score 2):

Code not tested but should work

```
package {
  public class SomeClass{
    public function SomeClass( ):void{
    }
    public function someFunc( val:String ):void{
      trace(val);
    }
    public function someOtherFunc( ):void{
      this['someFunc']('this string is passed from inside the class');
    }
  }
}


// usage 
var someClass:SomeClass = new SomeClass( );
someClass['someFunc']('this string is passed as a parameter');
someClass.someOtherFunc();







// mxml example
// Again untested code but, you should be able to cut and paste this example.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="someOtherFunc( )" >
  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      public function someFunc( val:String ):void{
        trace(val);
        this.theLabel.text = val
      }
      public function someOtherFunc( ):void{

        // this is where call the function using a string
        this['someFunc']('this string is passed from inside the class');
      }
    ]]>
  </mx:Script>

  <mx:Label id="theLabel" />
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions in flash are Objects, and as such function just as any object does. The AS3 api shows that a function has a call() method. you are very close in your code:

```
// Get your functions
var func : Function = someFunction;

// call() has some parameters to achieve varying types of function calling and params
// I typically have found myself using call( null, args );
func.call( null );  // Calls a function
func.call( null, param1, param2 );  // Calls a function with parameters
```

Comment: The first parameter of the object by default is the instance that the function belongs to (IE:"this")

Comment: oops I meant the first parameter of the fucntion "call" is the instance

Comment: @Ben: It gives the same error "Access of undefined property newFunc"

Comment: @sandy this isn't what you are looking for. This is just referencing a function through a variable, but you still need to get the function dynamically which this is not showing how to do.

Comment: @The_asMan:okay..den how dat is to be done..? In the answer posted by you, we have function in a different package. But for me the functions as well as its usage is in the action script of same mxml file

Comment: @sandy and mxml is considered a class I will edit my answer with a mxml version